# SQLAlchemy - build query filter dynamically from dict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I have a dict passed from a web page.  I want to build the query dynamically based on the dict.  I know I can do:

```
session.query(myClass).filter_by(**web_dict)
```

However, that only works when the values are an exact match.  I need to do 'like' filtering.  My best attempt using the `__dict__` attribute:

```
for k,v in web_dict.items():
    q = session.query(myClass).filter(myClass.__dict__[k].like('%%%s%%' % v))
```

Not sure how to build the query from there.  Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You're on the right track!

First thing you want to do different is access attributes using `getattr`, not `__dict__`; `getattr` will always do the right thing, even when (as may be the case for more convoluted models) a mapped attribute isn't a column property.

The other missing piece is that you can specify `filter()` more than once, and just replace the old query object with the result of that method call.  So basically:

```
q = session.query(myClass)
for attr, value in web_dict.items():
    q = q.filter(getattr(myClass, attr).like("%%%s%%" % value))
```

Comment: `getattr(myClass, attr)` doesn't have attribute `like`.

Comment: @Mohsen: pardon the friendly banter.  If you're having a problem using sqlalchemy, consider [asking a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask); I certainly can't reproduce the issue you seem to be having.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Thank you, your code solved my problem.... sorry for my first comment.....

Comment: How can a dynamic set of filters be constructed that use `or_` filter aggregation? As in, "(filter for field A like x) or (filter for field A like y)"? The x and y and possibly more options would be supplied through user input.

Comment: Any ideas how to implement nested filters? For example how to apply filter on myClass.subClass?