# Tool for generating SQLAlchemy queries from JSON-esque values?

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

I'm working on an application that does reporting-type things, and I often need to take a filter specified with JSON, convert that to an SQLAlchemy query, then send the results back to the browser (for example the filter `start_date: 1234, end_date: 5678, widget_ids: [1, 2, 3]` needs to be converted into the query `… WHERE start_date >= 1234 AND end_date <= 5678 AND widget_id in (1, 2, 3)`).

Is there a tool which will do this kind of conversion automatically (for example, using suffixes like Django's ORM: `start_date__ge: 1234, end_date__le: 5678, widget_id__in: [1, 2, 3]`)?

Obviously there would be security and performance implications of such a scheme… But I'd like to know if anything like this exists before I build one myself.

**Edit**: I realize that I could build my own thing, but I'm specifically wondering if there are existing tools/libraries, so I don't need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some simple code that may be of interest ([source](https://github.com/elemoine/papyrus/blob/master/papyrus/protocol.py#L108)):

```
def create_attr_filter(request, mapped_class):
    """Create an ``and_`` SQLAlchemy filter (a ClauseList object) based
    on the request params (``queryable``, ``eq``, ``ne``, ...).

    Arguments:

    request
        the request.

    mapped_class
        the SQLAlchemy mapped class.
    """

    mapping = {
        'eq'   : '__eq__',
        'ne'   : '__ne__',
        'lt'   : '__lt__',
        'lte'  : '__le__',
        'gt'   : '__gt__',
        'gte'  : '__ge__',
        'like' : 'like',
        'ilike': 'ilike'
    }
    filters = []
    if 'queryable' in request.params:
        queryable = request.params['queryable'].split(',')
        for k in request.params:
            if len(request.params[k]) <= 0 or '__' not in k:
                continue
            col, op = k.split("__")
            if col not in queryable or op not in mapping.keys():
                continue
            column = getattr(mapped_class, col)
            f = getattr(column, mapping[op])(request.params[k])
            filters.append(f)
    return and_(*filters) if len(filters) > 0 else None
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote something like that. I call it Python proxy. It provides a Javascript API to do RPC to Python, via JSON.

It's part of my open source project.

The pertinent files are:

http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/WWW/pycopia/WWW/json.py#135

Javascript side:

http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/WWW/media/js/proxy.js

Usage:

http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/storage/pycopia/db/webservice.py

Sample configuration:

http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/storage/etc/storage.conf.example

However, it's part of a complete framework, alas not well documented. Requires a recent Linux platform and some setup.

But maybe you can get some ideas from it.

Here is some other code that builds a query from a CLI style (argv) string. It does the dynamcic operator selection.

```
def _get_query(self, argv):
    mapper = models.class_mapper(self._obj)
    args, kwargs = _query_args(argv[1:], self._environ)
    q = _session.query(self._obj)
    if args:
        grps, left = divmod(len(args), 3)
        if grps:
            for name, op, val in _by_three(args[:grps*3]):
                col = getattr(self._obj, name)
                opm = {"=": col.__eq__, 
                        ">": col.__gt__, 
                        "<": col.__lt__, 
                        "match": col.match, 
                        "contains": col.contains, 
                        "in": col.in_, 
                        "like": col.like}.get(op)
                if opm:
                    if op == "like":
                        val = val.replace("*", "%")
                        val = val.replace(".", "_")
                        if "%" not in val:
                            val = "%" + val + "%"
                    if op == "in":
                        val = val.split(",")
                    q = q.filter(opm(val))
        for name in args[grps*3:]:
            if name.startswith("="):
                q = q.order_by(name[1:])
    if kwargs:
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            col = getattr(self._obj, name)
            value = CLI.clieval(value)
            q = q.filter(col.__eq__(value))
    return q
```

That might get you started, also.

Comment: Ah, I see. If I understand, though, [the query code](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/storage/pycopia/db/webhelpers.py#85) can only filter based on equality… no?

Comment: @DavidWolever I updated my answer to include some other code that does that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your sample, your `JSON` string does not really contain `operators`, so it is not clear whether it is one of `==, >=, <=, IN, etc`. Your `JSON` string can be easily converted into a `dict`.

For simple cases where you `have ==`, you can simply use [filter_by](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) providing a named dict:

```
query_dict = {'name': 'parent-2', 'description': 'test', }
query = query.filter_by(**query_dict)
```

Similarly, you can just build your query using `getattr` as answered in [SQLAlchemy - build query filter dynamically from dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605366/99594), but this still needs to know the `operator` of the condition. In the code below only `like` is used:

```
q = session.query(myClass)
for attr, value in web_dict.items():
    q = q.filter(getattr(myClass, attr).like("%%%s%%" % value))
```

If you need to dynamically specify the operator, then you can further use the `getattr`:

```
klass, attr, oper, value = MyClass, "startDate", "__ge__", 1234
q = q.filter(getattr(getattr(klass, attr), oper)(value))
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess the examples weren't very clear: I'd imagine that the tool would define some method for determining which operator should be used (ex, Django's ORM uses suffixes like `__in` and `__ge`). I realize that I could build my own thing, but this seems like a potentially common problem, so I'm wondering if there are any existing solutions.

Comment: (also, I think you've mixed up "operator" and "operand")

Comment: 2) A mix-up: good point - fixed it. 1) I think no tool can determine the `operator` automatically with 100% accuracy. I do see that `startDate` might imply `>=`, but it is as equally possible to be any of `==`, `>`, `<`, etc. `IN` could probably be inferred from the fact that the `operand` is a `list/tuple` (excluding strings).

Comment: Obviously heuristics would be a poor way determine the operator which should be used… But, fortunately, they are not the only way. As I mentioned, the Django ORM uses suffixes, and I'm sure there are many other sensible ways it could be done.