# Querying for floating point values in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, floating-point, sqlalchemy

To summarize the problem, I can not select any entity against a floating point value using SQLAlchemy.

For example:

```
m = session.query(Model).get(1);
all_m = session.query(Model).filter(Model.some_float_value, m.some_float_value)
```

all_m is empty while I would expect it to always have at least one!

How can I filter a float value in SQLAlchemy, based on an arbitrary precision (EG. some I may want to match to 0.01 or others I may filter with a precision of 0.0005).

For example, I want to be able to write a generic function so I can write queries like this in my code:

```
session.query(Model)\
    .filter(Model.foo == "bar",
            match_float(Model.some_float_value, float_val, 0.025)).all()
```

Where there tolerance of the matches anything within an approximate tolerance of 0.025.

However, I am not very familiar with SQLAlchemy, and was unable to locate documentation on how to create custom compare function, or any built in functions that would do what I need.

Is there a built in function I can use, a way to provide a custom compare function for the filter method, or do I a way to write a raw query/procedure for this?

Aditional Info:

Postgres 9.2

SQLAlchemy 0.9

Values are stored as double precision floating point

All Models were defined like so (there are a lot of them, which makes a solution with explicit column definitions less than desirable):

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost:1234/database')
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

class Model(Base):
    __table__ = Table('model', metadata, autoload=True)
```

*edit*

Iv'e completely reworded my question for clarity. Sorry for the confusion, I fail at communicating with humans...

Comment: What does "match to .01" mean to you?

Comment: It means match anything for (abs(a-b) >= 0.01)

Comment: Or in other words, it would only compare to 45.06. I can do all that stuff just fine. **What I don't know how to do is write a function that returns a valid match criteria for a parameter in the filter function. **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One concrete example for custom comparisons is shown in GeoAlchemy (though it may be overkill for your application). While the examples in the link below use bounding boxes for comparing spatial coordinates, you could use a simpler approach to implement comparison within a tolerance.

See for example the Comparator class which defines "~=" and other operators here:

http://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.4/spatial_operators.html

Since you mention that you were unable to find documentation on how to implement a custom compare function, see here:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#types-operators

On a related note - if you want to prevent database updates from being triggered if a floating point column remains within some threshold, see the discussion here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sqlalchemy/tCpsGZmjk_w/lOwW93qHV0sJ

(Disclaimer: This is based on a google search, I am new to SQLAlchemy)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changing the ORM isn't an option, but I may end up accepting your suggestion for custom type operators as a less-than-ideal solution if nothing better is presented. The models are many in number and all have a lot of fields. It will be very difficult to maintain and update without an auto-generated schema. even a wrapper function that injects a raw query would be a better solution, if it worked generically on any field I needed it to.

Comment: "Even a wrapper function that injects a query would be a better solution..." How about a variation of: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936111/sqlalchemy-can-you-add-custom-methods-to-the-query-object>

Comment: I believe the first comment there would still require custom type overriders. Also, what exactly did you have in mind for the override? Did you mean I should override the equals operator and send in a touple with a (VALUE,PRECISION) type of thing? The second comment had a broken link.

Comment: Not sure what happened to the link, here it is again: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/GlobalFilter

Comment: What I meant was: could you subclass Query, add a new method within_tolerance(self,epsilon,...) ? I'm not sure what options you are limited to, so I wanted to highlight this option of adding entirely new methods. I don't see that this approach requires custom types.

Comment: How would within_tolerance be called as a parameter to the filter function? Could you give me an example of what the final filter statement might look like? It seems like I would have to override one of the comparison operators to get it to work, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Example: I was thinking I may be able to do something like this, session.query(Model).filter(Model.some_float_value == (float_val, 0.025)) where I override \_\_eq\_\_ to accept a touple. The seems very dangerous without a custom type operator though.

Comment: Never mind, I just saw the recipe in the correct link you posted. That is exactly what I needed. Cheers!

Comment: My bad, didn't realize there was a separate button for the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

One of the rules of thumb for floating point numbers is "Never compare floating point numbers for equality." (You can Google that quote.)

The simplest and most predictable way forward is to use a SQL decimal(n,m) data type instead of a float. The SQL decimal(n,m) data type is free from errors of approximation.

[SQLAlchemy supports SQL decimals](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#sql-standard-types).

If you *must* operate with doubles, your best bet is probably to follow one of the two methods recommend by the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/fp/fpequal.html).

One problem with calculating the inequality `(abs(a-b) >= 0.01)` is that the result will be calculated using the closest floating-point approximations to `a` and `b`. Those floating-point approximations *might* be exactly the values you expect them to be, but that's application-dependent. (The decimal values 45.06 and 45.062 are not what you expect them to be when they're assigned to a double. In other words, the closest floating-point approximation to 45.06 isn't 45.06.)

The C FAQ has something to say about using this kind of expression as a general-purpose way of determining equality.

Comment: More precisely, it can represent finite decimal fractions exactly. Decimal is no better than binary at expressing pi or 1/3.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need to match double values at variable precession, not Decimal fields at a fixed precession . Would you be able to provide any insight on how I can do this?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan these values are in fact the result of fractional math on integer values, so your comment is very relevant. Thank you.

Comment: I apologize for not being more clear in my question. I know exactly how floating point numbers work. I need to know how I can query for them in SQLAlchemy. Is there a built in function I can use, a way to provide a custom compare function for the filter method, or do I need to use a raw query for this? Thanks for your time!