# What is the best way to create a SQLITE table with REAL values including a UNIQUE constraint?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, data-structures

I'm trying to understand the best way to deal with comparisons to floats in SQLITE3. Generally, I understand that it's a bad practice to test floats for equality. However, I'm not sure how else to do it in a SQLITE relational database.

Using the UNIQUE constraint on a row in a table is (by definition) testing for equality. So, is this a bad practice when working with a REAL datatype?

If I want to select that unique row, knowing only the REAL values, how should I do that?

I have the following table in SQLITE3:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes(
    node_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    node_number INTEGER,
    x REAL,
    y REAL,
    z REAL,
    UNIQUE(node_number, x, y, z)
);
```

For table inserts, I do the following:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO
    nodes(node_number, x, y, z)
VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

To find the node_id (for subsequent inserts), I do the following:

```
SELECT
    node_id
FROM
    nodes
WHERE
    node_number = ?
AND
    x = ?
AND
    y = ?
AND
    z = ?;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690512/7919597 You could check for something like `(abs(a-b) >= 0.01)`

Comment: Maybe you can define a custom `https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.UniqueConstraint` and overwrite the `__eq__`, but you'd have to ask the SQLAlchemy pros about that.

Comment: One of the suggestions in the link you provided was to use a DECIMAL type. However, when I read the Sqlite documentation, it seems seems like Sqlite just turns that into a REAL, whereas other database engines would work similarly to Python's Decimal class. I wonder if I might just multiply by my required precision (10^9) and store it as an integer? This all seems hackier than it should be to me.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, CHECK constraints cannot have subqueries, so if you want to perform a proximity-check in SQLite itself, you would have to use a trigger, e.g.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER notequal
   BEFORE INSERT ON test
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE
    WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT r FROM test WHERE abs(NEW.r - r) < 0.1))
    THEN RAISE (ABORT,'Value too close to an existing value')
  END;
END;
```

Of course you'd want the same thing for an UPDATE as well.

Comment: I didn't know about TRIGGERs. I guess you should change the 0.1 to the desired level of accuracy?

Answer (score -1):

One option might be to store the values as formatted strings and enforcing the UNIQUE constraint on that.

```
CREATE TABLE nodes(
    node_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    node_number INTEGER,
    x TEXT,
    y TEXT,
    z TEXT,
    UNIQUE(node_number, x, y, z)
);
```

Where the float values are stored in:

```
CREATE TABLE node_values(
    node_value_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    node_id REFERENCES nodes(node_id),
    x REAL,
    y REAL,
    z REAL,
    UNIQUE(node_id)
);
```

Inserts could look like:

Python

```
...
node_values = [
    (nnum1, x1, y1, z1),
    (nnum2, x2, y2, z2),
    ...
]
sql_insert_text_vals = """
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO
    nodes(node_number, x, y, z)
VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?);
"""
text_values = [
    (node_number, f'{xval:.10f}', f'{yval:.10f}', f'{zval:.10f}')
    for node_number, xval, yval, zval
    in node_values
]
cursor.executemany(sql_insert_text_vals, text_values)

sql_query = """
SELECT
    node_id
VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?);
"""
node_ids = [
    cursor.fetchone()[0]
    for value in text_values
    for cursor.execute(sql_query, value)
]

sql_insert_node_values = """
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO
    node_values(node_id, x, y, z)
VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?);
"""
real_values = [
    (node_id, xval, yval, zval)
    for node_id, (node_number, xval, yval, zval)
    in zip(node_ids, node_values)
]
cursor.executemany(sql_insert_node_values, real_values)
```

Is that better?