# SQLAlchemy filter_by not working with float column type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to filter by lat/long in a table of sites I have to prevent duplicate entries. However, I'm finding that filtering for these columns doesn't find a match that I would expect. Does anyone know why this filter might not be working? Thanks for any help

I am running these queries and comparing the results:

```
data_dict = {'lat':33.7838, 'lng':-117.225}

filter_test = session.query(Sites.lat, Sites.lng).filter(
        and_(
            Sites.lat == data_dict['lat'],
            Sites.lng == data_dict['lng']
        )
    ).all()

print(f'Filter test: {filter_test}')
no_filter = session.query(Sites).all()
for rec in no_filter:
   if rec.lat == data_dict['lat']:
       print(rec.country, rec.lat, rec.lng)
       print(rec.lat == data_dict['lat'])
```

The result from the first section (Querying with filtering) prints:

```
Filter test: []
```

However, the result of the second section (Querying all THEN filtering) prints:

```
United States 33.7838 -117.225
True
United States 33.7838 -117.225
True
```

My Sites table in SqlAlchemy looks like this:

```
class Sites(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sites"
    get_table_name = get_table_name
    country = Column(String(15))
    zipcode = Column(Integer)
    lat = Column(Float)
    lng = Column(Float)
```

Here is an image that shows a section of my sites table, with the records I am looking to filter for included:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this could be an issue in equal comparison to floating point number. It can be rather problematic to compare a python `float` value to a database floating point data type.

The safest way is likely to cast to decimal (`decimal(n,m)`) when performing the comparison

```py
from sqlalchemy import cast, DECIMAL

data_dict = {'lat':33.7838, 'lng':-117.225}

filter_test = session.query(Sites.lat, Sites.lng).filter(
        and_(
            cast(Sites.lat, Decimal(10,4)) == data_dict['lat'],
            cast(Sites.lng, Decimal(10,4)) == data_dict['lng']
        )
    ).all()
```

There are other options as well (multiply by a constant 10^n and cast to integer) when running the comparison, or also running a comparison for similar values / rounding values.

There is a similar discussion on a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690132/querying-for-floating-point-values-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out a solution by using a tolerance value. If the difference between the argument and the values in the table are below some Epsilon (0.005 in my case), then it properly fetches the expected results.

```
filter_test = session.query(Sites.lat, Sites.lng).filter(
        and_(
            func.abs(Sites.lat-data_dict['lat']) < 0.005,
            func.abs(Sites.lng-data_dict['lng']) < 0.005
        )
    ).all()
```

I looked at this link for help:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func