# Can you extend SQLAlchemy Query class and use different ones in the same session?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am using SQL Alchemy ORM and have some classes/tables each of which may have some custom queries. Let's say, I want to add to table `Fruit` the filtering possibility called `with_seed` giving me only fruits with seeds, and to table `Cutlery` the filtering method `is_sharp` giving me only sharp cutlery. I want to define these filters as extensions to the `Query` object, and I want to use them in the same transaction:

```
def delete_sharp_cutlery_and_seedy_fruits(session_factory):
  session = session_factory()
  session.query(Fruit).with_seed().delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
  session.query(Cutlery).is_sharp().delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
  session.commit()
```

Is this possible?

---

This is related to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15936111/1545579). But the solution there requires different sessions to be created for the different query classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass session to Query constructor

```
CustomQuery(entities=[Fruit], session=session).with_seed().delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
```