# How to change Column label using SqlAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, ms-access, sqlalchemy

I have MS Access DB file (.accdb), and inside of file stored photos of persons as attachments. In table constructor I see only one field "photos" with type "Attachment". Actually there three hidden fields with names: photos.FileData, photos.FileName, photos.FileType. For parsing these fields I created following class:

```
class Person:
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    name = Column(String(255), name='name')
    photos_data = Column(String, name='photos.FileData', quote=False)
    ....
```

If I try to get all attributes of Person in same time, as following:

```
persons = session.query(Person)
```

I get error in following generated piece of SQL statement:

```
SELECT ... [persons].photos.FileData AS persons_photos.FileData ...;
```

As you can see there dot sign present in alias, which raises ODBC error. I can avoid such behavior to request FileData as separate value:

```
persons = session.query(Person.photos_data.label('photos_data'))
```

Or I can use raw SQL without aliases. But This is not normal ORM way that I need, because I have to manually construct Persons object each time after request to DB.

Is it possible to set own label to Column **during its declaration** or even disable label for selected column?

I saw [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754209/why-does-sqlalchemy-label-columns-in-query), but seems this is not applicable to me. Below statement doesn't work properly:

```
photos_data = Column(String, name='photos.FileData', quote=False).label('photos_data')
```

Comment: So that alias is generated by SQL engine? And if you define alias causes issue? If this were query in Access, certainly could define alias.

Comment: Further to comment from @June7, you could try creating a view `CREATE VIEW v_persons AS SELECT [name], photos.FileData AS photos_data` and then base the `Person` class on the view rather than the table.

Comment: @June7 yes, this alias "persons_photos.FileData" automatically generated by SqlAlchemy. This alias doesn't work in queries inside Access - it is some kind of limitation of ODBC drivers. I hope that I understod your question.

Comment: @GordThompson, many thanks, I'll try to make it in SqlAlchemy. But I'm afraid that it migh be not possible, as possibilities of SqlAlchemy when declaring fields not too rich.

Comment: Right, in Access would have to enclose alias field name in [ ] because of the dot character.

Comment: @June7, seems that such autogenerated statement also gives me an error: SELECT ... [persons].[photos.FileData] AS [persons_photos.FileData] ....; The SqlAlchemy throws me an ODBC error: 'persons_photos.FileData' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long. (-1002) (SQLExecDirectW). So the problem is not in brackets, but in SqlAlchemy only. I need to change alias (label) of this column.

Comment: @Yurik - On second thought it occurs to me that basing the ORM object on such a view probably won't work because an ORM object must have a primary key. Instead, you might be able to use a make-table query (`SELECT … INTO … FROM …`) to create a temporary table, use ALTER TABLE to add an AutoNumber PK, and then attach the ORM class to that temporary table.

Comment: @GordThompson many thanks for your ideas. Your approach is too difficult for such small task. I will try to find SqlAlchemy solution how to rewrite auto-genereted alias.

Comment: @Yurik - If records in the table will have no more than one attachment then the view approach should work.

Comment: @GordThompson there can be many files/photos in one column, and I already find the way how to parse them. But the main question is still open.