# RESTful API different responses based on user roles

Tags: php, laravel, rest

i'm using Laravel as my PHP framework. its a convention to put `index show store ...` functions in controllers.

i have 2 types of users(Admin & normal user). lets assume there is an `Order`(in restaurant) model and i want to implement `index` function for its controller.
a user can have more than one Order.

what i need is that this function:

> - if admin is calling this API: returns all Orders
> - if normal user is calling this API: returns just Orders owned by this user

i searched but i couldn't find anything(tbh i didn't know what to search).

once i did this as below which i didn't like because it looks two different functions gathered in one:

```
if ($user->role == admin) {
       // fetch all orders
   } else if ($user->role == normal_user) {
       // just find user orders
     }
```

so my question is what's best approach to achieve  what i want?

Comment: If you're using the Query Builder, you could just conditionally wrap a WHERE clause for non-admins.

Answer (score 2):

Such a REST API endpoint is typically a search allowing multiple filters, sorting and pagination. If so it is completly fine to apply different defaults for filters and also restrict filters to roles.

I would auto apply a filter user=currentUser for missing admin role and return a forbidden if a user without the admin role tries to apply a user filter for a different user.

With this approach you give admins also the functionality to search for offers of a specific user and you only need one search api to be used by the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use an if statement?

You could make a scope on the model but then you'll still have an if.

What about this?

```
if ($user->role == admin) {    
    Order::all();
} else if ($user->role == normal_user) {
   $user->orders()->get();
}
```

Or make it an inline if

`$user->role == admin ? Order::all() : $user->orders()->get();`

IMO the best practice here is to make a different Admin/OrderController.php

Then with middleware check wat, the role of the user is, and then redirect them to the admin controllers.

Since you'll probably also want an update and delete, or other functions only accesible by an Admin

Comment: i don't think its good to move sth like delete and update of a controller to another one like admin. first clarity of code will be reduced because you expect all `Order`s functions be at same place. your first approach is exactly what i used before and what i didn't like at all. tnx for answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question myself a while ago and ended up with this strange solution to avoid that if/else block.

#### Assumptions

I assumed the existence of an helper method in the User model called `isNot($role)` to verify the if the user's role matches or not the given one.
This is just an example to give the idea of the check, but you should implement the condition as you like.

Second assumption I made is that each order has a `user_id` field which will reference the owner of that order though his id (FK of 1:N among user and order).

#### Implementation

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $orders = Order::query()
            ->when($request->user()->isNot('admin'), function ($query) use ($request) {
                return $request->user()->orders();
                // Or return $query->where('user_id', $request->user()->id);
            })
            ->paginate();

    return OrderResource::collection($orders);
}
```

The `when` method is the key here. Basically you call it like: `when($value, $callback)` and if `$value` is `false` the callback won't be executed, otherwise it will.

So for example, if the user is not an admin, you will end up executing this query:
`Order::paginate();`
that would fetch all the order with pagination (note that you could swap `paginate` with `get`.

Otherwise, the callback is gonna be executed and you will execute the `paginate` method on `$request->user()->orders();` (orders called like a method is still a query builder object, so you can call paginate on it).
The query would be:
`$request->user()->orders()->paginate();`

If you instead opted for the second solution in the callback you would basically add a where condition (filtering on the user_id of the orders) to the main scope to get only the user's orders.
The query would be:
`Order::query()->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->paginate();`

Finally, to better control what's sent back as response I use [Laravel's API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) (and I really suggest you to do so as well if you need to customize the responses).

**NOTE:** The code might have syntax and/or logical errors as it was just an on the fly edit from production code, and it hasn't been tested, but it should give an overall idea for a correct implementation.

Comment: i really loved your approach but i still think there is a better way, if i couldn't find any, your answer will be selected! thanks for sharing your experience

Comment: Then maybe take a look at the Visitor design pattern, but for small projects it might be overkill. You can read more about it [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor)

Comment: I would highly advise against mixing the query with the role checking logic, this will make the code dirty and very hard to debug or scale.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to include the if/else in your order modal like this:

```php
class Order extends Model {
....
 static function fetchFor (User $user) : Collection
 {
   return $user->isAdmin() ? self::all() : self::where("user_id",$user->id); 
 } 
}
```

then you can call this method on your controller

```php
public function index()
{
  return view('your-view')->with('orders',Order::fetchFor(Auth::user())->get())
}
```

Comment: i don't think using user role in Order model is a good approach. i would like to keep them not related as much as i can to avoid coupling.

Comment: you only have 2 roles, this is why i suggested this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can create scope in Order class...
For example you have field user_id in Order, for detect user

```
class Order 
{
 ...
 public function scopeByRole($query)
 {
   if (!Auth::user()->isAdmin())
     $query = $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
   return $query;
 }

}
```

in you controller just get all Orders with scope:

```
$orders = Order::byRole()->get();
```

it return you orders by you role

Also you need have in class User function for detect role, example

```
class User
{
  public function isAdmin()
  {
    // you logic which return true or false
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sure its good approach to enter something about user role in Order? i think its unrelevant and it cause coupling to grow up which is not a good thing.

Comment: If you have in Order model field for relationship with user, it mean what you have coupling user with order. I mean it solution is normal for you question