# Complex query in SQLalchemy with dictionary like in MongoDB

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymongo

## Problem

In pymongo, I can define my query using rather complex dictionaries:

```py
one_week_ago = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=7)
query_dict = {
    'name': {'$regex': 'John'},
    'age': {'$in': [25, 30, 35]},
    'created_at': {'$gte': one_week_ago},
}
results = collection.find(query_dict)
```

My understanding is that I cannot do this using SQLalchemy, but have to be more explicit:

```
query = session.query(User)
query = query.filter(User.name.like('%John%'))
query = query.filter(User.age.in_([25, 30, 35]))
query = query.filter(User.created_at >= one_week_ago)
results = query.all()
```

## Question

It seems to me that one could write a function which translates a complex query dictionary to a SQLalchemy-valid query (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605366/2135504 ). Does a library for this already exist? Or an alternative library to SQLalchemy for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a [where clause](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#the-where-clause) can accept an arbitrary number of arguments.

You are able to create a simple wrapper to convert the arguments from a dict to keyword vars, but it won't give you much benefit and will result in the same code more or less.

Finally, you can write as complex SQL queries as you want directly to the engine, but that defeats the purpose of using SQLAlchemy to a certain degree.